# Adobe photoshop cs6 not upgrading raw plugins in my macbook

Tags: adobe, adobe-photoshop

i tried to install raw camera plugin in my adobe photoshop cs6, but still not getting installed.

Comment: Your post misses a lot of details, especially versions of macOS and Raw Camera. If the answer you already got doesn't help you please add these details and also describe what you mean by "still not getting installed" (do you get an error message, can you install but the plugin is not recognized/activated, something else).

Answer (score 2):

It will depend what version of CameraRAW you are trying to install.

CS6 is no longer supported & the last version it is capable of handling is CameraRAW 9.1.1

Source: [Adobe Help - Camera Raw-compatible Adobe applications](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html)

For a workaround using DNG Converter, see [Update to camera support policy in CS6](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2015/07/update-to-camera-support-policy-in-cs6.html)